# How to reset $Line in each section?

Tags: notebooks, cells

When I evaluate my entire notebook, I'd like to reset $Line=0 at each section heading so all the code cells in that section are numbered starting from 1?

[image]

So in the above example I'd like `In/Out[3]` to be `In/Out[1]`. Is this possible with style sheets?

Comment: The number does not depend on the location of cells in the notebook. It depends on evaluation order.  Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?  Do you want to rewrite the cell labels, regardless of whether/when that cell was evaluated?  If yes, why?  Cell labels are not saved with the notebook anyway unless you change certain options.

Comment: You can use the output of `NotebookRead /@ Cells[]` to inspect the cells and probably accomplish what you want.

Comment: It really depend on what you want to do. Maybe it's what swish said, maybe it's just checking Evaluation -> Notebook's default context -> Unique to each cell group.

Comment: If you want each section to be independent of the others, then you could add CellContext->CellGroup to the style sheet for Input cells.